# Exception if no transactions are configured?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I am using spring/hibernate stand alone application. if i dont configure Transactions i am getting below excpetion.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

in spring/hibernate integrated application is  it mandatory to have transaction configuration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, yes. The [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation) says:

> Database, or system, transaction boundaries are always necessary. No
>   communication with the database can occur outside of a database
>   transaction (this seems to confuse many developers who are used to the
>   auto-commit mode). Always use clear transaction boundaries, even for
>   read-only operations. Depending on your isolation level and database
>   capabilities this might not be required, but there is no downside if
>   you always demarcate transactions explicitly. Certainly, a single
>   database transaction is going to perform better than many small
>   transactions, even for reading data.